# How to put a UISegmentControl on a UIToolbar as a ItemButton

Tags: uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I want have a view like iPhone's calendars app.
Anybody help to show me a demo? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post might be useful to you:

http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited

Comment: I'd strongly recommend putting the UIUSegmentedControl as a custom view to a UIBarButtonItem! Much simpler. `UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourSegmentControl];`